# Assign new value to variable using itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

This doesn't work but I can't see why it wouldn't? any help people? :)

```
params = qs.split("=", 2),
id = params[1];

if(id.indexOf("?") != -1){
  id = id.split("?", 1);
}
```

basically I want to change the value of 'ID' if the IF statement is true, if not.. it skips it and the value Id remains the default.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse the query string in not really the best way. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you provide a sample value of `qs` and the expected result?

Comment: Also there should not be any ? In a query string after having being parsed like it looks qs has been in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `id = id.split("?", 1)` is an array (of at most 1 item), but I think you want id to be a string.  That would explain why id is not a string like you want.

I agree with the other comments.  Please show us the URL string you want to parse and tell us which piece you're trying to get.  Usually, you look for `?` first, separate after that and then divide up various `key=value` sections.

If you had a URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com?foo=bar
```

Here's a simple function that gets you all the query parameters into an object:

```
function getParms(url) {
    var sections, key, pieces = url.split("?");
    var results = {};
    if (pieces.length > 1) {
        sections = pieces[1].split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
            key = sections[i].split("=");
            results[key[0]] = key[1];                          
        }
    }
    return(results);
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kNG3u/

Comment: @Maroshii - yes, if you want the part after the `?`.  See the general purpose function I added to my answer.

Comment: OK no need for function in the end, but thanks anyway will come in handy! the problem was like you said.. it was not a String and i was trying to use .length on it further down the code. A simple .toString() solved it. Thanks again.